# SQL for cases with 2 or more hits

Tags: sql

I have this table that has a lot of book related fields including keywords. Book_ids are primary keys. Let's say I have a book with six keywords describing it, now how do I search all the other books that have two or more same keywords?

What I have now is roughly this:

```
select book_id 
from book_fields
where keyword in ( select keyword from book_fields where book_id='123' )
```

The purpose is to get rough recommendations of similar books based on keywords. I'd like to do this with SQL if possible.

To clarify:
The idea is to match a book to other books using more than one keyword. All the keywords of all books were in book_fields table. No chance to touch the schema and RDMS was Oracle.

Comment: You'll have to be more explicit (at least, give us a hint) as to how the keyword field or fields are structured.  Hopefully, they are in a separate table with one keyword per record.  If not, are they in separate fields?  Or comma-delimited in a single field?

Comment: You need to post your table definition (column names, datatypes, and content), sample data, and the desired results. You haven't given near enough information to get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a one-to-many table, KeywordsToBooks, having the following schema:

BookID int
Keyword varchar

with both columns as PK, BookID as a FK to your Books table, and passing @BookToMatchID as the ID of the Book you want to match on as a parameter, here's what I'd do:

```
SELECT BookID, COUNT(BookID) AS KeywordMatches
FROM KeywordsToBooks
WHERE BookID <> @BookToMatchID AND Keyword IN (
    SELECT Keyword
    FROM KeywordsToBooks
    WHERE BookID = @BookToMatchID)
GROUP BY BookID
HAVING COUNT(BookID) >= 2
```

As other's suggested, if this doesn't help, can you post the relevant bits of your schema please?

Answer (score 3):

```
BEGIN;

CREATE SCHEMA books;
SET search_path TO books;

CREATE TABLE book_fields (
  book_id INT NOT NULL
, keyword VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (book_id, keyword) 
);

INSERT INTO book_fields (book_id, keyword)
VALUES
  (10, 'foo')
, (10, 'bar')
, (10, 'baz')
, (20, 'foo')
, (20, 'xxx')
, (20, 'baz')
, (30, 'yyy')
, (30, 'zzz')
;

SELECT
  lhs.book_id AS thisbook
, rhs.book_id AS otherbook
, COUNT(rhs.keyword)
FROM book_fields lhs, book_fields rhs
WHERE lhs.book_id <> rhs.book_id
  AND lhs.keyword = rhs.keyword
GROUP BY lhs.book_id, rhs.book_id
;

ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: +1 for the relational purity of joins. Does that make me a relationist?

Comment: Also, add `HAVING COUNT(rhs.keyword) > 1` to fulfill OP's requirement for two-or-more keywords in common.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that books are stored in the table named `books`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    books bo
WHERE   (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    book_fields bf
        JOIN    book_fields br
        ON      bf.keyword = br.keyword
        WHERE   br.book_id = 123
                AND bf.book_id = bo.id
        LIMIT 1, 1
        ) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

For better performance, do roughly what ristonj suggests, but avoid using the IN clause:

```
SELECT book_id, COUNT(*)
  FROM book_fields b
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM book_fields a
                WHERE a.keyword = b.keyword
                  AND a.book_id = '123')
 GROUP BY book_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This made an order of magnitude difference in the query this small query is part of.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be better addressed by creating a table which holds all keywords.

Is it feasible?